# Delphi: Разработка компонент со скинами

Tags: delphi, graphics, vcl

Хочу попробовать сделать на Delphi XE2 визуальные компоненты со скинами.
Например, кнопки.
Подскажите пожалуйста с чего начать?
Есть где-нибудь хороший материал, объясняющий как это сделать?

Comment: Добавьте больше информации в вопрос. Что конкретно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Если надо использовать родные скины, то тут лутший материал исходник VCL. Если нужно создать свою систему скинов,то можно посмотреть в сторону AlphControls или Delphi-IDE-Colorizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В XE2 есть встроенная поддержка стилей и редактор этих стилей. Вот описание работы со стилями [на сайте embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/VCL_Styles_Overview).
Вот [пример работы с этими стилями](http://www.webdelphi.ru/2011/10/delphi-xe2-i-vcl-styles/) на русском языке.
В комплекте стандартной поставки XE2 уже есть несколько готовых стилей. Подключить их к своему проекту можно таким образом:

> Project > Options > Application > Appearance

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будет как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]